# How can I call and endpoint on my Elastic Beanstalk server with Amazon Eventbridge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I want to create a scheduled job (cron), in which Amazon Eventbridge calls an endpoint from my application (hosted on Beanstalk) every X minutes.

According to the documentation, API calls are only mentioned for third parties outside of AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-destinations-with-amazon-eventbridge/

What is the best way to do this in a secure way?

PS: is this the best way to create batch jobs on AWS? I think so.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use EventBridge? I'd think using cron in ElasticBeanstalk is easier... https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/?nc1=h_ls